# What does "Goals" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does it mean "Wow" here?

> “That’s Bea Mason,” she’d said, and when I’d just stared at her,
> she’d rolled her eyes and said, “She owns Southern Manors? It’s, like,
> huge? I got that gingham skirt you like so much from there.
> “It’s her
> company?” I asked, looking back at my phone, keeping  my tone casual.
> “Oh yeah,” Charlie said as she reached to pick her daiquiri up off
> the nearby table. I could smell the sugary strawberry scent of it from
> my chair. “She’s super inspiring. Built it up from this little
> internet  business to a massive thing in like five years. Self-made
> multimillionaire. There was an interview with her in Fortune that my
> dad  sent to me, and I was like, **‘Goals**.’”

R.Hawkins "The Wife Upstairs"

Comment: Remind me to, like, never read that book. It's, like, really annoying, like, "avoid".

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - It's, like, crap?

Comment: @gonefishin'. It's Charlie that you dislike, not the book! The fact that the writer has been so successful in creating such an unlikeable character in a few lines to elicit a negative comment is testimony to her literary prowess. ;-) <br>
[The Wife Upstairs: A Novel](https://rb.gy/5jjlgy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially short for "Those are worthy goals to aim for", often used ironically.

In this case, Charlie is suggesting the idea of setting the goal of being a self-made multimillionaire in five years, probably as a joke.